# How do I create a string array that can be passed as parameter in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have tried multiple things but it is a game of guessing at this point

```
fn main() {
    let _array: [&'static str; 4] = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"];

    check_string(/*_array*/);
}

fn check_string(/*_input: ??? */) {


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to check the type of a variable in rust is doing this:

```
let val: () = /* your value */;
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d3c414fdcda21a3c9caa6abc18f61703))
Which gets you an error saying that it expected a `()` and not a `WhatEverYourTypeIs`
In this case you would get a `[&'static str; 4]` as you mention already in your code; so just require that in the function:

```
fn check_string(data: [&'static str; 4])
```

You could also pass a slice:

```
fn check_strings(data: &[&'static str])
```

And play with the lifetimes:

```
fn check_strings<'a>(data: &'a[&'a str])
```

etc.
To call it pass either:

```
check_string(_array);
```

If it takes a sized array or

```
check_strings(&_array[..]);
```

If it takes the slice.